# How to show elasticsearch queries in spring boot application

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am trying elastic search in spring boot application and I would like to debug on queries executed by ElasticsearchRepository.

tried 
`logging.level.org.elasticsearch.index.search.slowlog.query=INFO
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info=1ms`
but I didn't see the query print in log

Comment: Did you get any luck with this?

Answer (score 9):

Using Springboot 2.2.6, and `RestHighLevelClient`, the following worked:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE : trace
```

This is also documented in [springboot-data-elasticsearch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html)

However, you need to pay attention to initialize your `RestHighLevelClient` bean in the same way stated in the documentation. I.e, using the `ClientConfiguration` builder. 
At first I created the bean as `new RestHighLevelClient()` and it didn't work.
Example:

```java
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(esHost +":" + esPort).usingSsl()
                .build();

        RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
        return client;

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried other answer and it didn't worked in spring boot 2.2.2 and elasticsearch 6.7.2, the below worked for me probably because I use the `RestHighLevelClient`, to get the request and response body I had to enable the apache http logging in the application.properties files like below

```
logging.level.org.elasticsearch.client=TRACE
logging.level.org.apache.http=TRACE
```

Comment: Tracing like that is possible, but it will give you the low level request/response bytes transferred on the network, including the HTTP headers etc. Most probably, you are only interested in the Elasticsearch query itself. For that, you should create the client with :
RestHighLevelClient client = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
and set 
logging.level.org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE : trace

Answer (score 3):

In Spring Boot 2 you can enable query debug with the following:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core=DEBUG
```

And the generated log will be something like:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "some string",
            "fields" : [
              "nome^1.0"
            ],
            "use_dis_max" : true,
            "tie_breaker" : 0.0,
            "default_operator" : "and",
            "auto_generate_phrase_queries" : false,
            "max_determinized_states" : 10000,
            "enable_position_increments" : true,
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
            "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
            "phrase_slop" : 0,
            "escape" : false,
            "split_on_whitespace" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "version" : true
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to use the other answers, and finally recognized the problem as follows. Hope it helps for who has the same (wrong) way of doing it!

I originally use the "change logging level" functionality of Spring Boot Admin (which is a wrapper around spring boot `/actuator`) to change log level. It works perfectly for normal components, but strangely, it does *not* work for elasticsearch.

Thus, I have to write down

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE: TRACE
```

in my `application.yml`. And have to re-deploy the whole application. Then everything is ok and I see the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above do not log the request body and response body. If you want to log these, you need to configure as follows (tested in Spring Boot 2.3):

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.http.wire: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage()` so in source code there is an if condition;

```
    if (QUERY_LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        QUERY_LOGGER.debug(requestBuilder.toString());
    }
```

activate it by adding following line to logback-spring.xml in my case;

```
    <logger name="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.QUERY" level="DEBUG"/>
```